# How AWS hosted zone works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

How AWS hosted zone works and if the domain name is already bought from somewhere, where can I get NS records?

Comment: [Making Amazon Route 53 the DNS Service for an Existing Domain - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Route 53 is the host zone for AWS. Its highly available and scalable DNS web service. You can use Route 53 to buy domains from AWS. There is no such difference either you buy a domain from AWS or goDaddy or anyother domain provider. However the price of the domain varies based on the domain name. The name is premium then the cost will be high.
If you bought a domain from goDaddy, and wants to point to AWS. Follow the below steps,

- Goto Route53  and create a new A type record. You will get the NS record.
- Open goDaddy control panel and add custom Name servers against that domain.

Wait for few minutes so that DNS setting will take effect over the internet.